# React - How to apply multiple values from an object using context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, react-context

I use a color theme in my project for this, I used a React context to pass the value in several components, everything worked fine for me until I decided to add another property inside the object in order to apply different colors to different components, for example a `ThemeBackground` property that takes green as a value it will be applied to the `RoutesPage` component and a side property that takes an orange color it will be applied to the `SideBar` component. The problem is that I cannot apply the `side` property for the `SideBar` component, I tried several options, but I did not succeed right now, I will show you everything in more detail in the pictures so that you clearly understand the problem and then I will provide you with the code

[image]

Notice the `ThemesBackground` property is successfully applied to the content but the problem is that I want to apply the `side` property to my sidebar at the moment I imported the `ThemeBackground` property for my sidebar so my sidebar applies red color but I think you already understood the problem in short property `ThemeBackground` should be applied to content and `side` property to sidebar

**LessonThemes.jsx**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, createContext } from "react";
import SideBar from "./SideBar";
import RoutesPage from "../pages/Routes";

export const CounterContext = createContext(["color"]);


export default function LessonThemes(props) {
    const [BackgroundTheme, SetBackgroundTheme] = useState(localStorage.getItem("color"));

    const [themes, setThemes] = useState([
        { name: "G", ThemeBackground: "maroon", side: "orange" },
        { name: "R", ThemeBackground: "red", side: "aqua"  },
        { name: "B", ThemeBackground: "blue", side: "pink"  },
    ])

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("color", BackgroundTheme);
    })

    const SideBarPageContent = (SideBarPageContentBackground) => {
        localStorage.setItem('color', SideBarPageContentBackground);
        SetBackgroundTheme(SideBarPageContentBackground);
    }

    const list = themes.map((theme, index) => {
        return (
            <label key={index}>
                <input
                    onChange={() => SideBarPageContent(theme.ThemeBackground)}
                    type="radio"
                    name="background"
                />{theme.name}</label>
        );
    })

    return (
        <CounterContext.Provider value={[BackgroundTheme, SetBackgroundTheme]}>
            <SideBar list={list} {...props} />
            <RoutesPage path={props.match} />
        </CounterContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

**SideBar.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import {CounterContext} from "./LessonThemes";
import SideBarMenu from "./SideBarMenu";
import '../css/Sidebar.css'

export default function SideBar(props) {
    const [BackgroundTheme, SetBackgroundTheme] = React.useContext(CounterContext);
    return (
        <div className="wrappers">
            <nav id="sidebar" className="sidebar-wrapper modal">
                <div style={{background: BackgroundTheme}} className={"sidebar-page-content"}>
                    <div className="sidebar-brand">
                        <div className="sidebar-brand-container">
                            <div>
                                {props.list}
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <span href="#">Theme</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="sidebar-menu">
                        <SideBarMenu path={props.match.path}/>
                    </div>

                    ...
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I don't know if it will be useful to you or not, but in addition I want to demonstrate the `RoutesPage` component, although everything is in order there

**RoutesPage.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import {Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import '../css/Sidebar.css'
import {CounterContext} from "../components/LessonThemes";

function RoutesPage(props) {
    const {path} = props.path;

    const routes = [
        {
            path: `${path}`,
            exact: true,
            component: () => <h2>Home</h2>
        },
        {
            path: `${path}/Calendar`,
            component: () => <h2>Test123</h2>
        },
        {
            path: `${path}/Guardian`,
            component: () => <h2>Shoelaces</h2>
        }
    ];
    const [BackgroundTheme, SetBackgroundTheme] = React.useContext(CounterContext);

    return (
        <>
            <main style={{background: BackgroundTheme}} className="page-content">
                <div className="page-container">
                    <h2>Pro Sidebar</h2>
                    <hr/>
                    <div className="tabs">
                        <Switch>
                            {routes.map((route, index) => (
                                <Route
                                    key={index}
                                    path={route.path}
                                    exact={route.exact}
                                    component={route.component}
                                />
                            ))}
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
        </>
    );
}

export default RoutesPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that in the SideBar.jsx, the div style needs to be set to BackgroundTheme not SideBarBackgroundTheme? Also wouldn't it be passing in the object so you would still need to key into it for specific colors? Like BackgroundTheme.side?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `side` property is never being stored to the `value` of the context.  Your context value is still just a `string`.  The complete theme object exists is the local state of the `LessonThemes` component only.

In the `onChange` handler of your `input` you call `SideBarPageContent` which in turn calls `SetBackgroundTheme`, which updates the `BackgroundTheme` property which you pass to the context provider.  The argument that you are passing to this function call is `theme.ThemeBackground` -- which is the background color only and not the entire object.

You likely want to refactor your code so that the context contains the whole object.

Within the `SideBar` component, it's unclear where you think that the variable `SideBarBackgroundTheme` is coming from, but that variable doesn't exist.

Comment: This is my fault before I asked this question, I tried several options and forgot to change `SideBarBackgroundTheme` instead of this for now it should have been `BackgroundTheme` I of course edited my question but the problem is not solved

Comment: Do you understand the issue though?  That your context is just one single color and not an object with multiple colors?

Comment: I was able to solve this problem, I will answer my question soon

Answer (score 0):

**LessonThemes.jsx**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, createContext} from "react";
import SideBar from "./SideBar";
import RoutesPage from "../pages/Routes";

export const CounterContext = createContext([]);


export default function LessonThemes(props) {
    const [SideBarTheme, SetSideBarTheme] = useState(localStorage.getItem("SideBarKey"));
    const [PageContentTheme, SetPageContentTheme] = useState(localStorage.getItem("PageContentKey"));

    const [themes, setThemes] = useState([
        {
            name: "G",
            SideBar: "maroon",
            PageContent: "blue",
        },
        {
            name: "R",
            SideBar: "gray",
            PageContent: "green",
        },
    ])

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("SideBarKey", SideBarTheme, "PageContentKey", PageContentTheme);
    })

    const SideBarPageContent = (PageContent, SideBar) => {
        localStorage.setItem('PageContentKey', PageContent, 'SideBarKey', SideBar);
        SetPageContentTheme(PageContent);
        SetSideBarTheme(SideBar);
    }

    const list = themes.map((theme, index) => {
        return (
            <label key={index}>
                <input
                    onChange={() => SideBarPageContent(theme.PageContent, theme.SideBar)}
                    type="radio"
                    name="background"
                />{theme.name}</label>
        );
    })

    return (
        <CounterContext.Provider value={{
            SideBarValue: [SideBarTheme, SetSideBarTheme],
            PageContentValue: [PageContentTheme, SetPageContentTheme]
        }}>
            <SideBar list={list} {...props} />
            <RoutesPage path={props.match}/>
        </CounterContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

**SideBar.jsx**

```
export default function SideBar(props) {

    const { SideBarValue } = React.useContext(CounterContext);
    const [SideBarTheme, SetSideBarTheme] = SideBarValue;

    return (
        <div className="wrappers">
            <nav id="sidebar" className="sidebar-wrapper modal">
                <div style={{background: SideBarTheme}} className={"sidebar-page-content"}>
                    <div className="sidebar-brand">
                        <div className="sidebar-brand-container">
                            <div>
                                {props.list}
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <span href="#">Theme</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
...
```

**RoutesPage.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import {Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import '../css/Sidebar.css'
import {CounterContext} from "../components/LessonThemes";

function RoutesPage(props) {
    const {path} = props.path;

    const routes = [
        {
            path: `${path}`,
            exact: true,
            component: () => <h2>Home</h2>
        },
        {
            path: `${path}/Calendar`,
            component: () => <h2>Test123</h2>
        },
        {
            path: `${path}/Guardian`,
            component: () => <h2>Shoelaces</h2>
        }
    ];

    const { PageContentValue } = React.useContext(CounterContext);
    const [PageContentTheme, SetPageContentTheme] = PageContentValue;

    return (
        <>
            <main style={{background: PageContentTheme}} className="page-content">
...
```